# Can I group twice a Stacked bar with Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js

Can I group this chart in 4 seasons (Season 1, Season 2, Season 3, Season 4) and still show above each month on the chart (January, February, [...])

Starting example: https://fiddle.jshell.net/9xrb0vhe/2855/

Season 1: January,February,March

Season 2: April,May,June

Season 3: July,August,September

Season 4: October,November,December

Like for example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ym8u.png